# PHP remove string enclosed a parenthesis and after it

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove the string enclosed with parethesis and the other string on its right

Input:
   Hey (Jude) Hello

Expected Output:
   Hey

I can only achieve:
   `Hey Hello` by using this code

```
  $string = "Hey (Jude) Hello";
  echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "Hey (Jude) Hello";
echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\). */","",$string]);
```

The dot(.) Matches any character

The star(*) matches 0 or more of preceding character (aka the dot)

Check here for working example

https://regexr.com/3mb6e

Comment: This is much more effective. But other answers works but in some cases it doesn't but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
  $string = "Hey (Jude) Hello";
  echo preg_replace("/\([^)]+\).+/","",$string);
```